# pattern for composing functions

Tags: scala, scalaz

Following are a set of fictitious `case classes`. In reality we have got similar ADTs.

```
case class Alphabet(a:Character)
case class Word(alphabets: List[Alphabet])
case class Sentence(words : List[Word])
case class Paragraph(sentences : List[Sentence])
case class Chapter(paras : List[Paragraph])
```

There are service APIs as depicted below.

`def saveSentence(sentence : Sentence)`

`def saveParagraph(paragraph : Paragraph)`

`def saveChapter(chapter:Chapter)`

There are various kinds of tests which test above APIs. Test for `saveChapter` will prepare all required data to construct `Chapter` etc.

if you wanted to create "composable" functions where say

```
val alphabests :List[Alphabet] = ...
```

`generateWord(alphabests).compose` generates `Word` and likewise for other data. where output of previous function becomes input to subsequent function with necessary data built out from previous step for the next step.

What are the patterns you would use to achieve such behavior without being dependent on test framework (scalatest in this case)

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/wiki/User-Guide#generators)

Comment: If this is test data why not use functions from the test framework?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understood you right, but this functionality is already provided for scala functions.

```
 object Main extends App {
      def f(x: Int): Int = x * 2
      def g(x: Int): Int = x + 1
      def h(x: Int): Int = x + 100
      val x = g _ compose f compose h
      val y = g _ andThen  f andThen  h

      println(x(5))
      println(y(5))
    }
```

Here **x** and **y** are composed functions. Just don't pass actual parameter to your **generateWord**.